# How can I programmatically get a list nodes that a user can update?

Tags: organic-groups, users, database

I'd like to build a list of nodes which the current user is able to update. This is to be used in a site using Organic Groups.

My first hope was that there would be a Views filter that can check that the content is editable. Alas, no.

My second attempt was to use EFQ:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'suggested_listing')
    ->addMetaData('account', $account)
    ->addMetaData('op', 'update')
    ->addTag('node_access')
    ->pager(20);
```

would work, but it seems as though OG isn't setting the update column in `node_access`?

Comment: which hook are you targeting with tag ```node_access``` ?

Comment: I thought EFQ automagically used node_access so that tag isn't explicitly needed?

Comment: It does, I'm just belabouring the point. :-) Never the less, the node_access check only works correctly for op==view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following may be an inefficient way to do it as compared to EFQ - you first retrieve the nodes using db_select and check each node using node_access function, but it works the way you want it.

```
//build db query
$result = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->fields('n')->condition('status', 1)
        ->condition("type","suggested_listing", '=')
        ->execute();

        //fetch each node from database
         foreach ($result as $record) {

                $node = node_load($record->nid);
                //check if current logged in user has an update permission on the node being checked
                if(node_access('update', $node)){
                    //user has update permission to this node
                    var_dump($node->title);
                 }

    }
```

You can do similar thing using Views. Install the Views PHP module - https://drupal.org/project/views_php. It gives you a PHP filter. After you add a PHP filter, write following code.

```
 $node = node_load($data->nid);

  if(!node_access('update', $node)){
    return TRUE;
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There should be a view filter like that, but you'll need to use a relationship (Access log: User should do it) then add the filter called User: Permission.